# Redirect user after installing the app with a given link

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I am seeking for a way to generate a link that make user go to the app store or google play page of an app, based on their platform, to ask them to install the app. After they install through such a link, they should be redirected to a page once they log in successfully. The redirection should not occur if the app is not installed through such a link.

I checked iOS's universal link and Android's app link, which both seem to be working only if users have installed the app already. Is there a way to trigger that behaviour when it is not installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

> Dynamic Links work across app installs: if a user opens a Dynamic Link
> on iOS or Android and doesn't have your app installed, the user can be
> prompted to install it; then, after installation, your app starts and
> can access the link.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Links have been deprecated. I have not found a replacement for it yet.

https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq